# Getting the name which is not defined from NameError in python

Tags: python, exception, dynamic-data, expression, nameerror

As you know, if we simply do:

```
>>> a > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    a > 0
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Is there a way of catching the exception/error and extracting from it the value 'a'.
I need this because I'm `eval`uating some dynamically created expressions, and would like to retrieve the names which are not defined in them.

Hope I made myself clear.
Thanks!
Manuel

Comment: If it's not defined, how can it have a value?

Comment: I want to extract the name, not the value. I said "the value 'a'", not "the value of a".

Comment: Why do you need to use `eval`? If you want to create a Python shell, this is not the right tool. If you want to create an expression evaluator for your application, this is not the right tool.

Comment: What would be the right tool? -.- You could include that in your previous comment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> try:
...     a>0
... except (NameError,),e:
...     print re.findall("name '(\w+)' is not defined",str(e))[0]
a
```

If you don't want to use regex, you could do something like this instead

```
>>> str(e).split("'")[1]
'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import exceptions
>>> try:
...     a > 0
... except exceptions.NameError, e:
...     print e
... 
name 'a' is not defined
>>>
```

You can parse exceptions string for '' to extract value.

Answer (score 1):

No `import exceptions` needed in Python 2.x

```
>>> try:
...     a > 0
... except NameError as e:
...     print e.message.split("'")[1]
...
a
>>>
```

You assign the reference for 'a' as such:

```
>>> try:
...     a > 0
... except NameError as e:
...     locals()[e.message.split("'")[1]] = 0
...
>>> a
0
```