# Can I Skip Parameters in Python When Using Kwargs

Tags: python, function, dictionary, parameters, keyword-argument

I have a function that takes in kwargs. I want to use the kwargs parameters by name without having to declare each explicitly as either a parameter or variable. Is there a way to use `my_var_key` by passing in kwargs *without* having to specifically define it in the function call, or is the only way to use `kwargs[ "my_var_key" ]`?

E.g. I want something like

```
def func(**kwargs):
    print(my_var_key)
```

as opposed to

```
def func(my_var_key, **kwargs):
    print(my_var_key)
```

or

```
def func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs[ "my_var_key" ])
```

I'm okay with it breaking if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Why don't you just pass in a dictionary and work on that dictionary?

Comment: You possibly could do something by wrapping your code in `try ... except NameError` to catch a `NameError`, [*parse* the `NameError` error message to extract the variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270795/getting-the-name-which-is-not-defined-from-nameerror-in-python), and then look up the extracted name in `kwargs` ... but that's very gross and brittle, and I'm not really sure what that would buy you.  Is there any motivation for this other than to reduce some typing?

Comment: @jamesdlin For motivation, let's say (this is extreme for illustration) you had five functions where each takes in 100 arguments. Say that most of those arguments are going to be the same keyword but some arguments will exist that aren't in the others. The functions also use them all very differently. I don't want to have to explicitly declare 100 variables five times, but there's too any unique parameters to make doing a common subset worthwhile either. The best is to have a kwargs dict of all the common plus unique parameters, defaulted to empty values, and pass that to each function.

Comment: I would probably try to use a decorator to reduce the boilerplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this. It makes your code harder to read.

But if you insist, try modify your `globals()` scope:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    for key, val in kwargs.items():
        globals()[key] = val
    print(globals())
    print(my_var_key)

func(my_var_key='foobar')
```

and the output is:

```
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10f058f28>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'test.py', '__cached__': None, 'func': <function func at 0x10ef52268>, 'my_var_key': 'foobar'}
foobar
```

This will surely pollute your global namespace (and you cannot use `locals()` because the interpreter confuses). Again, don't do this.

Comment: Why even post this answer?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's good to know what's possible in a language, even if it's not best practice to actually do it

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no practical way to get the syntax you want.

One part of [Python's design philosophy](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is that "explicit is better than implicit", so there are not many situations where names will get added to your namespace without your input. If you want `my_var_key` to be put into your function's namespace when it's passed as an argument, you should just name it in the `def` statement. If you want it to only be passable as a keyword argument (not a positional one), you can put a `*` in the argument list:

```
def func(*, my_var_key): # arg can only be passed as a keyword: func(my_var_key=1)
   ...
```